# Setting a SeekBar value

Tags: android, seekbar

I am creating a simple height calculation application using a SeekBar and two TextViews.
The first one is for feet and the second one for inches.
I want it so that if the value goes above 12, it will automatically reset to 0 and the height should be increased by 1.

How can I do that?

This is what I have done so far:

```
height_seekbar.setProgress(68);
        height_feet_textview.setText(String.valueOf(5));
        height_inches_textview.setText(String.valueOf(8));
        height_seekbar
                .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // height_seekbar_textview.setText(seekBar.getProgress()
                        // + " ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                            int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        //progress += 60;
                        int feet = progress / 12;
                        int inches = (progress % 12);

                        height_feet_textview.setText(String.valueOf(feet));
                        height_inches_textview.setText(String.valueOf(inches));

                        Log.i("BodyProfileHeightWeightActivity",
                                "Progress of seekbar" + progress);
                        // if (progress >= 12) {
                        //
                        // height_seekbar_textview.setText(0);
                        //
                        // }
                        // String heightSelected = String.valueOf(progress);
                        // height_seekbar_textview.setText(heightSelected);

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply below logic:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
    int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    progress += 60;

    int feet = progress / 12;
    int inches = progress % 12;

    txt_feet.setText(String.valueOf(feet));
    txt_inches.setText(String.valueOf(inches));
}
```

Comment: This works but i want to set the value of inch textview to 0 again when it is greater then 12.

Comment: This will work. For ex. if progress is 48 then txt_feet will be 4 and txt inches will be 0.

Comment: You can also help me. If this is correct solution then you can upvote my answer and if this answer is what you were looking for then you can mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Unfortunately you will not be able to upvote. You will need minimum of 15 reputations. Thanks for accepting BTW. :)

Comment: one more thing...i want to set minium value to 5.0. how do we do that

Comment: Minimum 5 feet. Right?

Comment: Yes...minimum should be 5 feet 0 inch

Comment: add seekbar.setProgress(60); in your onCreate() method.

Comment: i have already call the setprogress method to set the default value of seekbar.

Comment: i have used this in my code to set the default value which is 5.8 height_seekbar.setProgress(68);
  height_feet_textview.setText(String.valueOf(5));
  height_inches_textview.setText(String.valueOf(8));

Comment: It is not working...it extends the maximum limit to 12.0

Comment: What is the maximum height that you want to allow?

Comment: maximum value should be 7.0

Comment: then add 'android:max="84"' in your xml.

Comment: yes i already added it...i want minimum value to be 5.0,maximum value to be 7.0 and default value to be 5.8

Comment: i have successfully set maximum value and default value but now i want to set minimum value....see my edited code

Comment: //progress += 60; remove comment here

Comment: i have tried but it will set the maximum value to 12.0

Comment: <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/height_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearlayout_bodyprofile_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:max="84"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_layer"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_selector" />

Answer (score 0):

```
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if(progress>=12){
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: If i set setprogress value to 0 the round wheel goes back to starting point